# How Apache Spark streaming builds time windows

Tags: apache-spark, stream, window

What is a logic in Spark SQL (2.3) that makes windows with week interval  to always start on Thursday? 
For example: `select x,y,z from mytable group by window(datetime_col, "1 week")`

Answer (score 0):

`window` is not the best choice for the application like this. It makes more sense to use `next_day`:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY next_day(datetime_col, 'Thu') - INTERVAL 7 days
```

The same thing with `DataFrame`:

```
df.groupBy(next_day($"datetime_col", "Thu") - expr("INTERVAL 7 days")).agg(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trail and error on Apache Spark 2.3.0 these are my conclusion:

For Fixed (thumbing) window:
The start date is 1/1/1970 (Epoch time).
For example window(dt, "180 days"), for event at 1/12/2017 and window of 180 day. If you count windows of 180 days staring from 1/1/1970, the date 1/12/2017 will fit to the 98's which is [2017-10-21 - 2018-04-19].
Also 1/1/1970 was a Thursday. If you have windows with weeks as interval. it will start at Thursday.

For Sliding widow:
The window is created for the earliest window that the event is in.
For example, for event ate 1/12/2017 and window of 180 day siding with 1 day. The windows that will be create will start at 5/6/017 - 2/12/2017 and since the window is sliding you will have 180 windows (5/6/017 - 2/12/2017, 6/6/017 - 3/12/2017, 7/6/017 - 4/12/2017, ...)